# Why Blender Cycles is not able to detect my GPU(s) and CUDA within the Ubuntu / Linuxulator

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I've just installed Ubuntu 22.10 with the Linuxulator on FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE p6 as well as these components inside it :

```
nvidia driver Version: 525.78.01 + CUDA 12
Blender 3.2.2
```

The nvidia driver 525.78.1 + CUDA 12 work correctly within the linuxulator :

https://ibb.co/8Ps8J81

and Cycles is already able to detect the nvidia driver + CUDA,but only if blender runs on FreeBSD. Give a look at this picture :

https://ibb.co/rwZ7q8Q

What I want to do is to run Blender and I want to render my projects with cycles using the CUDA libraries and my GPU(s) within the linux emulation layer. Is this supposed to work ? The error that Blender gives when I try to do that are the the following ones :

```
root@marietto:/# blender

Read prefs: /root/.config/blender/3.2/config/userpref.blend
libGL error: glx: failed to create dri2 screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
could not get a list of mounted file-systems
/var/run/user/1001/gvfs/ non-existent directory
Saved session recovery to '/tmp/quit.blend'
Blender quit
```

why do I use root ? because as a normal user Blender does not start at all.

```
marietto@marietto:~$ blender
Unable to open a display
Aborted
```

I'm very curious to understand the reason(s) of the errors I see below :

```
libGL error: glx: failed to create dri2 screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
```

My sensation is that they can be fixed. If I do :

```
cp -r  ./blender-3.2.2-linux-x64/3.2/scripts/addons/cycles/lib /compat/ubuntu2210/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/
```

I see this additional error :

*CUDA cuInit: Unknown error*

but if I remove the lib directory :

```
rm -r /compat/ubuntu2210/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/lib
```

the error *CUDA cuInit: Unknown error* disappears,but the other errors are still there.

It seems to me that Blender looks for the nouveau driver and it can't find it. But it should look like the nVidia driver. Since the nouveau driver does not support CUDA,maybe it should be "unlinked" from Blender and Blender should be "linked" to the nvidia driver,in some way. What do you think ?

Comment: Free BSD is off topic on this site. If the question is limited to Ubuntu then that is on topic.

Comment: For me it's enough to gather some technical informations for the ubuntu part.